# Jenkins CLI prompting ssh phasphrase

Tags: java, jenkins-cli

I'm using :

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://sample.url online-node  machineName -noKeyAuth
```

and its still prompting a passphrase as :

```
enter passphrase for C:\Users\username\.ssh\id_rsa:
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created your key, did you give it a passphrase?

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:
```

If so, you will have to provide that passphrase every time you use the key.

If you really need to keep a passphrase on your key, you can always create a separate key for automation:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.automation
```

When you are prompted for the passphrase, just hit the `[Enter]` key.

When you created your key, were you following this guidance from the [Jenkins SSH documentation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222838288-SSH-Credentials-Management-with-Jenkins)?

> **Passphrase**
>
> When generating your SSH key pairs, it is recommended to protect your SSH private-key with a passphrase.

Adding a passphrase does add an extra level of security. However, the cost is that you must provide the passphrase each time the key is used.